# windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, PID, False): Process_all_Access not defined

Tags: python, ctypes

me again. I'm continuing my journey with C and Python.

Today, I happened to be making a debugger.
Currently, this is what I have

```
    from ctypes import *
    from Debugdeclares import *

    kernel32 = windll.kernel32
    class debugger():
        def __init__(self):
            self.h_process = None
            self.pid = None
            self.debugger_active = False

        def load(self, path_to_exe):
            creation_flags = DEBUG_PROCESS
            startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
            processinfo = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
            startupinfo.dwFlags = 0x1
            startupinfo.wShowWindow = 0x0
            startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo)
            if kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe,None,None,None,None,creation_flags,None,None,byref(startupinfo),byref(processinfo)):
                print("[n] Process launched")
                print("[n] Process location: %s" % (path_to_exe))
                print("[n] PID: %d" % (processinfo.dwProcessId))
                self.h_process = self.open_process(processinfo.dwProcessId)
                return processinfo.dwProcessId
            else:
                print("[n] Error: 0x%08x." % (kernel32.GetLastError()))

        def open_process(self, pid):
            h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,pid,False)
```

---

This is where the error spot is, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS is not defined. However, in the ctypes library, there is an input of that keyword. I have attempted using strings, byte strings, but to no avail. Here is some additional information [about the OpenProcess function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320.aspx) and [about the Process Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880.aspx)

---

```
            return h_process

        def attach(self, pid):
            self.h_process = self.open_process(pid)
            if kernel32.DebugActiveProcess(pid) == True:
                self.debugger_active = True
                self.pid = int(pid)
                self.run()
            else:
                print("[n] Unable to Attach Process")

        def run(self):
            while self.debugger_active == True:
                self.get_debug_event()

        def get_debug_event(self):
            debug_event = DEBUG_EVENT()
            continue_status = DBG_CONTINUE
            if kernel32.WaitForDebugEvent(byref(debug_event), INFINITE):
                input("[n] Nothing to see yet...")
                self.debugger_active = False
                kernel32.ContinueDebugEvent( \
                    debug_event.dwProcessId, \
                    debug_event.dwThreadId, \
                    continue_status )
        def detach(self):
            if kernel32.DebugActiveProcessStop(self.pid):
                print("[n] Finished debugging. Exiting...")
                return True
            else:
                print("[n] There was an error")
                return False


    debugger = debugger()
    pid = debugger.load(b"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe")
    debugger.attach(pid)
    debugger.detach()
```

So really, I'm asking: What's a bug fix?

Much Appreciated!
-Norton

EDIT:
Oh yes!
here is my Debugdeclares script:

```
    from ctypes import *

    WORD = c_ushort
    DWORD = c_ulong
    LPBYTE = POINTER(c_ubyte)
    LPTSTR = POINTER(c_char)
    HANDLE = c_void_p

    DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010

    class STARTUPINFO(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
        ("cb", DWORD),
        ("lpReserved", LPTSTR),
        ("lpDesktop", LPTSTR),
        ("lpTitle", LPTSTR),
        ("dwX", DWORD),
        ("dwY", DWORD),
        ("dwXSize", DWORD),
        ("dwYSize", DWORD),
        ("dwXCountChars", DWORD),
        ("dwYCountChars", DWORD),
        ("dwFillAttribute",DWORD),
        ("dwFlags", DWORD),
        ("wShowWindow", WORD),
        ("cbReserved2", WORD),
        ("lpReserved2", LPBYTE),
        ("hStdInput", HANDLE),
        ("hStdOutput", HANDLE),
        ("hStdError", HANDLE),
        ]
    class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
        ("hProcess", HANDLE),
        ("hThread", HANDLE),
        ("dwProcessId", DWORD),
        ("dwThreadId", DWORD),
        ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your error message tells you exactly what's wrong: `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` isn't defined, because you haven't defined it anywhere. I don't know what "in the ctypes library, there is an input of that keyword" is supposed to mean, but `ctypes` doesn't define it for you.

In fact, the only place in the Python standard library where `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is mentioned is in an undocumented C extension used by the `multiprocessing` module:

```
>>> from _multiprocessing import win32
>>> win32.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS
2035711
```

Using that is probably a bad idea, because it is, as said, undocumented.

Because `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is a macro, there's no way to find out its value through something like `ctypes` at runtime, so if you want it, you'll have to look up what it is for your system and define it yourself in your code. Though it's probably a better idea to heed the warning in [the documentation you linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880.aspx) and figure out a minimum set of access rights instead.

Answer (score 2):

`PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = (0x000F0000L | 0x00100000L | 0xFFF)`

done.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for my issue. :-)
Basically - I was using a different Access modifier, which was giving me the IntPtr, but for some reason, not with enough permissions to get the ProcessToken's current elevation. With this change, I am now getting the proper elevations from my script.

Answer (score 1):

```
h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,pid,False)
```

this should be.

```
h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
```

checkout MSDN reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There can be two ways to define the value to the **PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS** :

Either define its value as :

```
   PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x001F0FFF
```

OR

Use *_multiprocessing* library:

```
   from _multiprocessing import win32
   h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess(win32.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False,pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Gray Hat Python book, you gotta read WARNING on page 30.

Download my_debugger_defines.py and replace it with your current copy.